# Teradata- insert records from UPI table to NUPI table

Tags: teradata

How the data will be distributed among the AMPs if the records are inserted to a  NUPI table from a UPI table? Will the data be copied and retained in the same AMP as that of original one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Teradata rows are distributed by the hash of the Primary Index columns, there's no difference if the PI is Unique or Non-Unique.

To check on which AMP a value will be stored you can use the built-in hash functions:

```
select hashamp(hashbucket(hashrow('any value(s)/column(s)')));
```